# Is it possible to stream live video from iOS device to iOS device in own app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, http-live-streaming

Similar to face time or Skype I want to have that feature inside of my app.  I have found HTTP live streaming but that seems not to be able to go from device to device.  Is this possible to do?  Is their any sort of API out there for it?  This will be made for an iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

HLS is not a good idea for this. Using HLS will mean extremely high latency (at least 2 seconds). I would recommend using SIP+RTP, which is what FaceTime and other video calling systems use.